# UWP WebView2 not working with WebView2 Runtime installed

Tags: c#, uwp, webview2

I've created a WinUI 3.0 UWP application and installed the WebView2 runtime as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution).
When I inspect the regkey and its pv property, per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#online-only-deployment), it is set. However, when launching my app, regardless of in debug or release, I see the **A suitable version of Microsoft Edge was not detected**

The XML itself is extremely simple:

```
<Grid>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<controls:WebView2 x:Name="MyWebView"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Source="https://www.microsoft.com" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

The documentation states that it should be possible to rely on the WebView2 runtime for development as well:

> During development and testing, you may use either as the backing web platform.
>
> - The WebView2 Runtime
> - Any Insider (non-stable) Microsoft Edge (Chromium) browser channel

Have anyone managed to get this running without installing a BETA release of Microsoft Edge directly as this is not an option nor is it [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#understanding-the-webview2-runtime).

Comment: The WebView2 Runtime is AFAIK only supported for Win32 applications: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winui does not mention the Runtime as  an option.

Answer (score 0):

See the prerequisites in [Getting started with WebView2 in WinUI 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winui)

[Introduction to Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)

To see which version of MS Edge is required for a particular version of WebView2, see the [WebView2 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/releasenotes).

Download the latest development build of MS Edge from https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download.

The following post shows some things that you can check to determine the MS Edge version(s) you have installed. [How to detect if runtime is installed? #421](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/421)